# Why is "decimate" still linked to its number-specific definition when other similar words are not?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

As any pedant will tell you, *decimate* means “to destroy a tenth of something.” Of course, its modern usage has been expanded to this:

> 1. to destroy a large number of (plants, animals, people, etc.)
> 2. to damage or destroy a large part of (something)
>
> (Merriam-Webster)

Almost every modern use of the word *decimate* is in this expanded sense. However, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimate), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/decimate?s=t), [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decimate), and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/decimate?searchDictCode=all) all list the historical “destroy a tenth” definition along with the modern definition, and it’s not uncommon for people to argue that this is the *only* definition that should be allowed for the word--even though the word in that sense is rarely, if ever, used (The British National Corpus gives [23 results](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=Decimate&mysubmit=Go) for *decimate*, 21 of them using the modern definition and the remaining two complaining about the use of the modern definition).

However, there are plenty of other words whose definitions have been expanded beyond their original number-specific etymologies, such as *alternative* and *combine*, and you don’t see anyone causing a stink about those. Is there a reason why people want to cling so desperately to *decimate*’s literal definition? What’s the point of trying to enforce a definition that no longer has any de facto existence?

**EDIT: Some people asked for examples of people complaining about *decimate* being used with the expanded definition rather than the historical one. Here are some examples:**

[This website](http://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/decimate.html) lists using *decimate* in this way as an error.

[This Oxford Dictionaries blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/09/does-decimate-mean-destroy-one-tenth/) addresses the "linguistic pet peeve" of people who complain about *decimate* being used this way.

[This NPR article](http://www.npr.org/blogs/ombudsman/2011/10/24/141665070/on-language-do-you-mean-decimate-or-devastate) quotes the senior supervising producer of their Arts & Life section, who says,

> "I think the people who defend the original meaning of 'decimate' do
> so in part because we feel it's sad to lose a word for describing
> something so precisely and in a way that evokes such history. I guess
> one can substitute 'collective punishment' or 'culling.' But every
> time we let word meanings bleed together, it's like a little star
> winking out."

Comment: People need something to complain about.  And there aren't nearly enough *real* problems in the world to suit some people.

Comment: I suspect it's because the root _dec_ is still used to refer to 10 in so many other words, so the link is very obvious. There's no such recognizable root in _alternative_ and _combine_.

Comment: But the root _bi_ is still used to refer to 2 in many other words, too, so how did _combine_ get its meaning expanded without complaint?

Comment: @Nicole It's not as obvious that _bi_ is the root of _combine_.

Comment: Just looking at the words *alternative* and *combine*, I couldn't tell you what, if any, numbers occur in their etymologies. The *dec-* at the beginning of *decimate*, on the other hand, is immediately obvious, and anyone who has even a passing acquaintance with the metric system will know that it means 10.

Comment: Note that it is the same with the French 'decimer' and the Italian 'decimare'. The Latin root 'decem' ..respectively dix and dieci!!

Comment: What is the number specific etymology of alternative?

Comment: It comes from the Latin word for "other" and originally meant "the other of two options."

Comment: Many of us get annoyed when linguistic drift spoils a useful tool - when my son uses my best chisel as a can-opener, for instance, or Microsoft randomly changes the Word interface. There's not much to be done about it, but it's cathartic to rant.

Comment: "it’s not uncommon for people to argue that this is the only definition that should be allowed for the word" - could you provide a few specific examples? The expanded meaning is so overwhelmingly used that I've never heard the claim made. Or is it just that you move in pedantic / Latin History circles?

Comment: I (emphasis on I) cause a stink with some folks' use of the word alternative! I might even have the temerity to say to them, "Don't you mean to say OPTIONS instead of alternatives?" Hey, we all have our sensitivities and hobby horses. People are funny that way. Don

Comment: A better question is why "decimate" no longer means "punish".  The original meaning was to kill every tenth member of a group, to punish the group.  It makes more sense to go loosey-goosey on the one-in-ten thing than to forget about the punishment aspect.  Even if monarch butterfly populations are reduced by exactly 10% due to habitat destruction, I find it hard to believe that that destruction was intended to punish monarchs.

Comment: The answer's in the third word of the question: pedantry.

Comment: @Nicole What part of the word 'alternative' describes a number?

Comment: @DaveMagner It comes from the Latin word for "other" and originally meant "the other of two options."

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I edited my post to add links to some examples.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I've frequently encountered posters on Usenet newsgroups that have nothing to do with language or history who rant about "misuse" of _decimate_. Some people just can't understand that language evolves, and is defined by how it's used, not historic precedent. I'm not sure why they fixate on this particular one, particularly as the original meaning is so specific that it's practically useless.

Comment: Not just practically useless. I'm not aware of any military units being decimated in the last, oh, 1500 years or so, although I may be mistaken. While the phrase might well be applied to, for instance, civilian populations which provided hostages to the Third Reich as protection against insurgent activities, I'm pretty sure the exact 1 of 10 ratio was not observed - so the example fails. There's an excellent critique of the issue here http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/09/does-decimate-mean-destroy-one-tenth/, and it's entirely possible that the pedants have the wrong of it.

Comment: Interestingly, the plot of Stanley Kubrick's _Paths of Glory_ hinges on a modern (World War I) counterpart to decimation: After a failed assault on enemy trench positions, each unit of the French army involved in the assault is ordered to surrender one man to be executed for cowardice. It may not have been based on historical events, but in the context of the utter cynicism of the French General Staff's prosecution of the war, the punishment comes across as both plausible and horribly corrupt.

Comment: It is more common now for decimate to imply a loss 90 percent rather than 10 percent.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, *decimate* isn't the only word linked to its number-related root. You will still find people who, for example,  mentally connect *hecatomb* with the sacrifice of 100 oxen, *myriad* with the number 10,000, and *millennarianism* with 1000 years in Christian eschatology. I'm one of them.

To me, these connections don't provide a compelling reason to banish use of any of these terms in nonnumerical settings, but they do enrich my sense of where the words came from and perhaps hint at how they came to be applied in the situations in which they are commonly used today.

Ultimately, etymology doesn't provide a persuasive basis for denying the legitimacy of the way people use words today when it departs from the way people used them decades or centuries ago. But words do have a past, and getting annoyed when people bring up that past seems to me no more productive or sensible than getting annoyed about the fact that meanings evolve.

Comment: This is all true—but while I've seen many argue out of misguided pedantry that _decimate_ should never be used in the extended sense, I've never seen anyone argue that _hecatomb_ should never be used to refer to anything but the sacrificial slaughtering of exactly 100 oxen, nor even that _myriad_ should only be used to mean exactly 10,000. And I've certainly never seen anyone complain that what they were drinking should not be called a fruit punch because it doesn't contain exactly five ingredients. So the question remains: why are people so hung up on _decimate_ in particular?

Comment: @Janus: I think Barmer's comment above helps explain the phenomenon. _Decimate_ looks so much like _decimal_ that many people with a not-very-deep awareness of etymology (certainly not deep enough to notice the _bi_ component of _combine_) make the connection between _deci_ and "one-tenth." Many people think of pedantry as the preserve of academics, but I think it exists on a continuum that ranges far into popular culture—and the greater the number of amateurs (like me) who know some stray fact, the more likely that fact is to become a point of pride (and pedantic insistence) to glorify.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just a bit wary of that explanation because I personally (even as someone who dedicates a great deal of my life to etymology) never made any connection between _decimate_ and _decimal_ at all until I learned of the original (and never-used) meaning. I had always intuitively parsed it as _de-cimate_, without really thinking much about what _*cimate_ might be (but possibly grouping it mentally with _incinerate_, etc.). Then again, that's anecdotal and it may be just me.

Comment: Your wariness is surely justified. In my experience, people rarely complain that December ought to be renamed because it is no longer the tenth month of the year, so the explanation for pedantic enthusiasm over _decimate_ can't be that the "Uphold the Purity of Deci-" lobby is unusually strong and equally active on all fronts. But that doesn't prove anything about a _decimate/decimal_ connection. My position is simply that I haven't seen an explanation (or even a suggestion) that seems more plausible than Barmar's.